How do I prevent unwanted object properties from the client in nestjs
when i use

whitelist: false,
forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
forbidUnknownValues: true

it didn't prevent any unwanted object properties .so please give me the answer below is my code
app.useGlobalPipes(
new ValidationPipe({
  whitelist: true,
  exceptionFactory: (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) => {
    Logger.debug(`Class Validator error:${JSON.stringify(validationErrors)}`);
    return new BadRequestException(validationErrors);
  },
  transform: true,
  forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
  forbidUnknownValues: true  
}),

);
give me the solution
